# SSIS going in sleep mood with parallel execution of a one of the package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package. In the package there are several packages. In one package the task is to execute around 25 stored procedures. I have divided those 25 stored procedures in 8 block. 8 blocks run in parallelly. I found that while executing those stored procedures at random time the SSIS goes in sleep mood without giving any error. Sometimes its in sleep mood for 1 hour, sometime it is in sleep mood for more then 12 hours.

I tried multiple things like instead of 8 blocks i tried 4 blocks, the result is same. But when i run all the 25 stored procedures 1 by 1, the ssis does not goes into sleep mood. it completes all the task including executing 25 stored procedures within 4 min.

[image: SSIS was in sleep mood from 10th jan 10.38 pm. Finished on 11th jan 3.13 pm]

SSIS was in sleep mood from 10th jan 10.38 pm. Finished on 11th jan 3.13 pm.

[image: This is the Main SSIS Package]

This is the Main SSIS Package.

[image: This is the inner package at step 6 where 25 SP run]

This is the inner package at step 6 where 25 SP run. Currently it is designed in 8 block. In each block 3 SP's , runs 1 by 1. Each blocks run separately

I need some help regarding why it is going in sleep mood. What i need to do to prevent this.

Thanks
MD. Atibur Rahman

Comment: Seems from your description your stored procedures block each other

Comment: Each Stored Procedures Reads data and generate new  data according to logic and Insert the data to a fixed table. 25 stored procedures 25 tables. Each tables does not have any dependency between them.

Comment: Install [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) on the server that has the procedures running. Kick off the packages and once you think it's "sleeping" start running sp_whoisactive and look at what the active processes are, what wait types are associated to your activities and most importantly, look at what shows up on the blocking list

Comment: I have installed sp_whoisactive.
Wait_info is null.
sql_text shows me the sp but from SSIS i found that the SP is finished. After finishing the sp no new sp initiated.

Comment: also executed sp_who2 and found that SSIS status is sleeping

Comment: I found that when i am running SSIS from Visual Studio it is running perfectly. But when i am deploying it in the SQL Server it is going in sleep mode. 

Any Suggestions would be great. Thanks